How to read heic image from project bundle folder?
I have added the image to the project bundle folder, and I'm attempting to read those images using the following code,
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName", in: bundle, compatibleWith:nil)

In this case, the result is always nil. However, the same code successfully reads PNG or JPEG images.
Can anyone help me understand why it's not reading HEIC images here?

Maybe unrelated but Apple recommends you use png or jpeg files in the app bundle for size and compatibility reasons.

HEIC is an image formate which is introduced by apple and when compare to PNG or JPEG size of the image is to low, for that reason using this image.

Put it in the asset catalog.

While not including the file extension works for PNGs and JPGs, you should include the file extension for HEIC.
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName.heic", in: bundle, compatibleWith:nil)

